# Confusion about Interpolation

Tags: interpolation, documentation

Assume I have obtained a table of values,`{x,y}`. Now I want to interpolate them with `Interpolatiion`.

If I write `Interpolation[{x,y}]` will I get `x[y]` or `y[x]`? It is not clear to me from the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`y=Interpolation[{{x1,y1},{x2,y2},....}]` returns an interpolation object which gives `y[x]`